# Defining the size of array using variable

Tags: c++, c, arrays

Is this valid in C language?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i = 5;
  int a[i];     // Compiler doesn't give error here. Why?
  printf("%d",sizeof(a));  //prints 5 * 4 =20. 4 is the size of integer datatype.
  return 0;
}
```

Compiler doesn't give error at the statement `int a[i];`. i isn't a constant then how can it compile successfully? Is it because I am using gcc compiler? Is it allowed in C++?

Comment: Th discussion in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21273849/1708801) about what is a constant expression with respect to variable length arrays is relevant.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, this is valid as of [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99), and is called a [variable-length array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (VLA). In other words, it has been in an official language standard for around 14 years.

No, it's not valid in C++, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c) for details.

Also note that `sizeof` is not a function, so that can be written as `printf("%zu\n", sizeof a);` which also uses the proper format specifier for a `size_t` value.

Comment: Ok thanks. Also does gcc compiles a c program using rules for c++ ? I can declare variables after using printf function and it doesn't give error.

Comment: @user221458 Please *read* the text about C99, since you seem to be very much unaware of the language you're trying to use. You can declare variables more freely in C99.

Comment: VLA is supported in C++ too. I just checked it.

Comment: VLA is not part of C++, it's supported by that compiler as an extension to C++. In other words code using VLAs will probably not compile if you use a different compiler.

Comment: So it is just limited to gcc.

Comment: Note that gcc/g++ with -std=c++14 won't support this anymore - the sizeof() will generate a warning and incorrect code.

Answer (score 2):

This is valid *C99* it is called [Variable Length Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)(*VLA*) `gcc` supports [VLA as an extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html#Variable-Length) outside of *C99* mode with respect to *C++* both [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla) support variable length arrays as an extension even though this is really a *C99* feature.

You can build using the `-pedantic` argument in `gcc` and `clang` both will give a warning similar to the following:

```
warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla-extension]
```

`sizeof` is expected to work correctly with *VLA* although it will be evaluated instead of an integer constant. Although you do have [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code since you specified the wrong format specifier for *`size_t`* which is `zu` and not `d`. The [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) in section `7.19.6.1` *The fprintf function* which `printf`'s section refers back to for the format string paragraph *9* says:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.[...]

Answer (score 0):

I'd just add to unwind's answer that in C++14, there will be runtime-sized arrays, which work pretty much the same as VLA.

See chapter 8.3.4 in [N3690](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf) (`array of runtime bound of T`)

They seem to be supported in clang-3.3 (in C++1y mode), but NOT in GCC 4.8 (the support should come in GCC 4.9).
When you write the code in pre-C++14 mode (c++03, c++11), your code will probably compile, but it should issue a warning about using a C99 feature not supported in C++.

And you always should compile with most pedantic warnings enabled :)

Answer (score -1):

`Sizeof` operator is compiler independent.

You could read more about this in the following links ::

[VLA-as-function-argument](http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/vla-as-function-arguments/)